# Determine Pragmatically the width of a div inside an iFrame via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, width

I have a div.  That div lives inside an iframe. That div has a width.  I would like to get this width via jQuery.  Attached are some of my adventures in doing so. Please enjoy!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvkdd.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z09Pt.jpg

*EDIT* - Also why does my console throw errors if I start any line with a $ ?

*EDIT 2*  - Simplified the question to bare bone basics.

Comment: the item you are trying access is in an iframe. you might be experiencing this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: @PlantTheIdea from my understanding of that article, it's talking about loading cross domain content.  In my example I changed the URL, but the both parent and child are in the same domain.

Comment: you shouldn't have stopped after the first answer, because the second is valuable. its the same as the one @joao answered.

Comment: You say your console throws errors when you start a line with $. I suspect you either don't have jQuery loaded on the page, or you have another framework bound to $ aswell. Try running just '$' and post the results, also try running just 'jQuery' and post the result.

Comment: $ - undefined | jQuery - function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. Although my workaround for this issue is working, I had several other issues with jQuery on my site.  Namely, the $ not working in the console.  I knew I had jQuery referenced, yet $ wasn't a valid object.

It turns out that when jQuery is running in non-conflict mode, the $ is not available in the standard use case.  Instead you pass it the document ready function like so:

jQuery(document).ready(function ($){

Now it is a valid object and can be used as normal.  This allows jQuery to run in non conflict mode and still have access to the $

You can read about this HERE: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

(jQuery noConflict Wrappers section)

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you can do something like this:

```
$("#iframeId").contents().find('#divId').width();
```

Since your iframe don't have a id, either change that or find it by other means, you can use $('iframe') to list all iframes in your document. In relation to your tries if you use $('.span9') this will find all elements with this class, so you also need to find another way to get your element.

Comment: If you need more help on this issue just ask :P

Comment: I tracked down the code and added an ID to the iframe called "gameframe" and an ID to the span9 called "gamebox"

http://i.imgur.com/Y9MB6Sg.jpg

Comment: your frame have jquery included? this code is correct you must be doing something else wrong,

Comment: I do think something else is afoot.  In the meantime I just used PHP to lookup the size of the swf on the server, and then threw that into the echo'd javascript.  Works. Not as I intended for it to, but it works.  Thanks for all the help buddy.

Comment: try to type only $('#frameID') and see what object is returned in console... i am sure this is the correct code. And if you can check the scipt tags in your header for jquery

Answer (score 0):

Using `$("#IDofDIV").width();`
You will need to use an ID instead of a class for the element you want to resize/get the width of. Classes house many elements, there could even be hundreds of elements with the same class. You need to specify which element, not a group of elements.

So using an ID would be the easiest thing although there are many other ways.

[Here is a link to `.width();` documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Also you are using an iFrame so you may have trouble just running scripts from the console. See the first comment under your question where @PlantTheIdea has given an explanation for this.

Comment: Let me have a stab at this.  I'm using a Wordpress plugin (lighbox plus colorbox) to achieve the iframe, so I'll have to hack up their code to add an ID.  I'll be back ASAP.

Comment: I have tried accessing it via ID now, and still same errors.  (see comment above)